# How to make a library replaceable in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, architecture, interface, module

I’m searching for a way to make a library replaceable. 
For example: I have a library which is managing communication over multicast . I’m using that library in my main application. My idea was to use an interface for that:

```
public interface MessageHandler {
    public void sendMessage();
    public Message receiveMessage();
}
```

Now it should be possible to change the library. For example a library which is managing communication over broadcast. Both are implementing the same interface.

So in my main application I want to have the opportunities:

```
MessageHandler mHandler = new MulticastImpl();
```

Or

```
MessageHandler mHandler = new BroadcastImpl();
```

My problem is: Where do I place the interface definition? When I place it into my main application I can’t see it from the library (because the library don’t know the main application). 
When I place it into the both libraries I have two different MessageHandler-Interfaces (for example com.multicast.MessageHandler and com.broadcast.MessageHandler)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic plugin system.  what you should do is:

1. put the plugin API in a standalone jar.
2. include this plugin API jar in the main application.
3. plugin implementations should *not* include the plugin API (they will just use it for compiling).
4. provide a way for the user to specify the "implementation" class for the plugin (as a configuration String)
5. on application startup, use reflection to load the implementation class from the configuration.

Note, there are more sophisticated ways to load plugins in java (e.g. using java.util.ServiceLoader and/or nested classloaders), but this is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You use the library Interface, don't put them on both. The Library is defining the interface used to communicate with it.

On your main application you want to program using the library interface, then you can switch to diferent implementations of it without changing your code, just the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions but the (putting the interface i both libraries or
having the interface in a library of its own), but you need to have one name
for the interface, for example com.messaging.MessageHandler.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy pattern can help here.

If you want a library be replaceable, define a Strategy
that encapsulates what this library does.

Everywhere in your code, just call the Strategy,
not the library. The Strategy will then choose which
way to go.

After having done that, you can replace the Strategy encapsulated
with any other Strategy or library.

[More information on Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DI](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) for this. You will inject the implementation by your favorite DI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This question is "answered" but anyway, I'd like to bring you another perspective.

You should look into OSGi and service modularity as a way to achieve seamless replacement of implementations of the same service logic. OSGi strongly enforces separation of interface and implementation and provides a modular architecture with 'bundles' that can even be (re-) deployed at runtime.

You could have a "MessageHandler" service with MulticastMessageHandler as an implementation.

We have e.g. a Data Store that has a switchable  noSQL and a SQL datastore as backend. The application never notices/don't case which one is in use.

Eclipse has Equinox OSGi, which is included in your Eclipse dev environment.